# How do I increase the amount of decimal points?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, time, decimal

This code is used to estimate pi, with the highest objective being time efficiency. With this in mind, I need to increase the amount of decimal places, as currently it is bottlenecked down to 2.

```
import numpy as np

def main(max_iterations=200):
    a, b= np.random.random(max_iterations), np.random.random(max_iterations)
    return 4 * (a ** 2 + b ** 2 < 1).sum() / max_iterations

main()
```

Example of current output:

```
3.13
```

One thing I noticed was that upon adding 0s to the max_iterations parameter, the number of decimal places increased along with it. Though, I need a solution within the function, where it wouldn't matter what the value of the parameter was.

Example of what I want as an output:

```
3.127722772277228
```

Comment: If you divide an integer by 200 the result will have either two decimal places (omitting trailing zeros), three decimal places where last digit is 5 or sometimes less than two decimals. Math doesn't allow other results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't divide an integer by a number with trailing zeros if you want more significance.

With `max_iterations=200:`

> %Run pi_test.py
> `3.08`

With `max_iterations=201:`

> %Run pi_test.py
> `3.084577114427861`